# Rails Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on implementing an outside API in my rails app.

In the docs it says to add these into the POST request:

```
accept: application/json

content-type: application/json

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

So far I've implemented:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://example.com")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json', 'Accept' =>'application/json'})

response = http.request(request)
```

Which should cover the `Content-Type` and `Accept` criteria. But I'm struggling to figure out how to implement the `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`. Does anyone know how I should do that?

Thanks!

Comment: in the same way as you did for the other 2? add it to the `initheader` hash

Comment: So just like a `request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json', 'Accept' =>'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate'})`

Comment: yes. I think it should work. Did you try?

Comment: Well I think I may have some other things wrong with my request atm, so hopefully this works :)